# Dissolving by common name and boundaries using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I am looking for a way to merge or dissolve polygons from the same shapefile that both share a common attribute (in this case, owner name) and area adjacent to each other/share a common border. Just using the normal dissolve tool by owner name combines polygons which are not connected, which I would like to leave separate.

Is there a way to manipulate the dissolve tool inputs or a different tool that can achieve this?

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

[image]

I currently work around this by using the edit tool, highlighting all the commonly owned parcels, and merging if they are contiguous, but this gets very time consuming with larger datasets.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain additional details instead of commenting  on your own Question. Have you attempted to with use Multipart to Singlepart or encode a cluster ID or othe attribute on which to Dissolve?

Answer (score 4):

In the dissolve tool, dissolve by Owner name but make sure to uncheck 'Create Multipart Features'. The default setting of the dissolve tool has this checked:

[image]